# Go Custom error processing error interface reporting results to actual error?

Tags: go

I have been trying to understand the Go Custom error handling by following examples here: https://golangbot.com/custom-errors/
for last example in this playground: https://play.golang.org/p/5-5CagJKW67

it says

In the main function, we check whether the error is not nil in line no. 4. If it is not nil, we assert it to type *areaError in the next line. which is

```
if err != nil {
        if err, ok := err.(*areaError); ok {
            if err.lengthNegative() {
                fmt.Printf("error: length %0.2f is less than zero\n", err.length)

            }
            if err.widthNegative() {
                fmt.Printf("error: width %0.2f is less than zero\n", err.width)

            }
            return
        }
    }
```

Then using the lengthNegative() and widthNegative() methods, check whether the error is because of the fact that the length is negative or width is negative.

What I dont understand is that the methods: lengthNegative() is not checking the length it is only sending an error. How are we checking if error is type length

```
func (e *areaError) lengthNegative() bool {
    return e.length < 0
}
```

I think It has to do with: err.(*areaError)   but somehow in : err.lengthNegative()  the err which has the info that length was < 0 info is passed as a receiver to lengthNegative()

Comment: What do you mean by:  *"`lengthNegative()` is not checking the length it is only sending an error."*? `lengthNegative()` *is* only checking the length, it is *not* sending an error.

Comment: I c whats happening the return is a bool so if -->   return e.length < 0    then bool will be True

Comment: Yes, it's semantically equivalent to `if e.length < 0 { return true } else { return false  }`